# NodeJS Mongoose : Catch CRUD Error and send back a custom message to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongoose

### Environment

- **NodeJS 10**
- **MongoDB**
- Client app : **Angular 9**

### Description

I have a controller and a service on the NodeJS side that create an entity and send back a promise like this :

#### Controller

```js
    async create(@Body() entityData: any) {
        return this.getService().create(entityData);
    }
```

#### Service

```js
  newInstance(obj:any={}):T{
     return new (this.getRepository() as Model<T>)(obj);
  }


  async create(entityToCreate): Promise<T> {
    let toCreateUpdated = this.newInstance(entityToCreate);
    return toCreateUpdated.save(); //This returns a promise
  }
```

### Question

Is there a way for me to catch errors like **duplicate fields** or something and sending back a custom message to my client?

I tried to use **try/catch** or just **catch** on promises but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
async create(entityToCreate): Promise<T> {
    let toCreateUpdated = this.newInstance(entityToCreate);
 try {
    return await toCreateUpdated.save()
 } catch(error)
        console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code. Pure code answers are discouraged here in SO. In addition, please take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).